# Xcode 5.1.1: where did they move device orientation?

Tags: xcode, device-orientation

So, I updated Xcode and a bunch of stuff has been consolidated/hidden for the project settings. I only have the Info and Build Settings tabs. Where did they move the spot where you can set your allowed device orientations? Also, where can I add libraries/frameworks now? That used to be under Build Phases but it's completely gone!

Here's a screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're confused between editing the *project* and editing the *target*. What you want is the target.

This is not new at all, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, realized my mistake. After the upgrade, Xcode selected the project instead of the target for me and that was what led to my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation
[Download screenshot](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/b96369f8)

Comment: That doesn't exist anymore. All you have now under Info is Deployment Target, Configurations, and Localizations. See the screenshot above that I'm going to add right now.

Comment: Never mind. I'm an idiot. I had the whole project selected, not the Target. My bad.